# Why is the AESni flag missing for my i5 CPU

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, dm-crypt

My CPU is reported by Intel to support the AES-NI native instructions. http://ark.intel.com/products/65707

However, `/proc/cpuinfo` does not list the `aes` flag (which is what I guess is preventing me from installing the `aesni-intel` kernel module -- my ultimate goal is to have `dm-crypt` use the benefits of HW acceleration).

How can this be? 
If the CPU allegedly has the feature, what is preventing it from being recognized by the OS? (I already installed Arch's `intel-ucode` to have the newest microcode on the CPU.)

`cpuinfo` output (shortened):

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x19
cpu MHz     : 1445.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
siblings    : 4
cpu cores   : 2
cpuid level : 13
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
```

Comment: You need a [kernel that supports it](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL.html), and it looks like the option needs to be enabled at kernel build-time. This would be independent of the CPU's microcode.

Comment: Some vendors have aes-ni disabled for some reason, and a bios update is required to enable it. Not sure if this applies to your CPU, but it does to others. (see "Some products can support AES New Instructions with a Processor Configuration update" on the ark intel page you linked to)

Comment: @frostschutz Crypto export could be a reason — there are country pairs (A,B) such that it's illegal (either in country A or country B) to export crypto hardware or software from country A to country B. Maybe shipping a CPU with AES circuits that cannot be used barring a firmware upgrade is legal even where shipping the circuits enabled would be illegal.

Comment: It seems there is a BIOS update available for my Laptop, unfortunately this a Windows binary. I'll try to get the update installed somehow -- maybe this (re)enables the AES support.